# How to restart loop enumerating lines?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, if-statement

I am trying to scrape some information from a URL as the figure. Sometimes one item is available in one line and other in two different lines. There is no standard when it is in one line or two.

[image]

When is only in one line, I use `[i+1]`. While in two lines, I use `[2*i+1]`. What is the best way to continue the loop until no more lines are available in these two different conditions?

```
for i, registro in enumerate(elements):
    if browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td').text:
      try:
        empresa = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                    f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td[2]').text
      except:
        empresa = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                    f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{2*i+1}]/td[2]').text
```

The code line `if browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="grdDocumentos"]/tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td').text:` is responsible to find items with two lines.

0

The full code is available in https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9ybtvyqa90n28e/code.txt?dl=0 I am expecting to have all items exported to telegram.

Comment: Please provide the html code in text with your expected output.

Comment: I expect to have all items enumerated in order of appearance. Some items are not enumerated, some examples is when are some items in two different lines and appears other in one line, this one is out of enumeration. I am using this enumeration in order to send the items to telegram.

Comment: Ok, so please add the html code in text containing items in a single line and items in two different lines in your question and include your expected output of the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is something like `groupby` to group the rows by class odd/even. i don't know how to do that with selenium nor xpath, but i'll show you how to do it with beautifulsoup

```
from itertools import groupby
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml') # with data as your html content
trs=soup.select('tr')
trs.pop(0) # the first tr has no class odd/even i think it's the dropdown menu

for klass, group in groupby(trs, lambda x:x['class'][0]):
    print(klass, list(group))
```